# If pushforward by equivariant map of structure sheaf is structure sheaf and the space of sections isomorphic, are they isomorphic as G-modules?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, equivariant-maps

Apologies for what may very well be a trivial question from a non AG person. Suppose I have a morphism of varieties $f: X\rightarrow Y$, with $Y$ affine,  which is equivariant with respect to the action of a compact Lie group G. Suppose I know that $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_X \simeq\mathcal{O}_Y$ (in my case Y is a rational singularity), and 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = H^0(Y, \pi_*\mathcal{O}_X) \simeq \Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)
\end{equation}

Is it true then that $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ and $\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ are isomorphic as $G$ modules?

My issue is I don't know what 'form' the isomorphism $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_X \simeq\mathcal{O}_Y$ takes, and so don't know if I can use the equivariance of the map $\pi$. Given the above isomorphism what is the way to obtain sections of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ from those of $\mathcal{O}_X$?

I'd also like to know if the same is true for the canonical sheaf, i.e. if the statement is also true replacing $\mathcal{O}_X$ with $\omega_X$ in all of the above.

Comment: Is the isomorphism $\pi_* O_X \cong O_Y$ obtained by pullbacking functions ? If yes then yes to your question. If no, it's hard to answer with no more informations.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure. I've heard that one can claim $\pi_* O_x \cong O_Y$ if $\pi$ is a proper birational map with $Y$ normal, and that this implies that the fibres of $\pi$ are connected. In that case one can intuitively imagine functions on $X$ which are constant on the fibres of $\pi$ to be canonically identified with functions on $Y$, as in Karl Schwede's answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf.

Comment: Is there some general statement for rational singularities which claims that the isomorphism is obtained via pulling back functions?

Comment: The existence of the map $\mathcal O_Y \to \pi_* \mathcal O_X$ has nothing to do with rational singularity. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $U \subset Y$ open, we have $\mathcal \pi_*\mathcal O_X(U) = \mathcal O_X(\pi^{-1}(U))$. So when one has a function $f : U \to \Bbb A^1$  we can take its pullback $f \circ \pi \in \pi_* \mathcal O_X(U)$. Pullback commutes with restriction and hence define a map of sheaves $ \mathcal O_Y \to \pi_* \mathcal O_X$.

So unless stated otherwise, $\mathcal O_Y \cong\pi_* \mathcal O_X$ means specifically that the previous map is an isomorphism. In your case, it is a $G$-equivariant map so indeed the global sections are isomorphic as $G$-modules.

However in the setting of algebraic geometry it is more commun to have a reductive group rather than a compact Lie group (for example, the complexification of your compact Lie group if you look over $k = \Bbb C$).

The answer is the same with $\mathcal O_X$ replaced by $\omega_X$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think what I should have written instead of rational is "normal variety". I agree pulling back functions is equivariant, but I'm not sure if I see why $\mathcal O_Y \cong\pi_* \mathcal O_X$ implies the pullback map is an isomorphism?

Comment: What I meant was that in math papers, the formula $\mathcal O_Y \cong \pi_*\mathcal O_X$ means "the pullback map induces an isomorphism $\mathcal O_Y \cong \pi^* \mathcal O_X$".

Comment: I see, and the same is true for arbitrary sheaves?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what is the analogous statement for "arbitrary sheaves", but any functor constructed from $f_*,f^*$ etc will be $G$-equivariant if $f$ is.

Comment: As in, if someone writes $\pi_* \omega_X \cong \omega_Y$ they really mean the pullback map induces the isomorphism

Comment: Exactly ! ${{}}$